# Color overlapped portions of multi line chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

My code is as follows:

```js
var data = [
  
  {
    name: "Canada",
    values: [
      {date: "2000", price: "200"},
      {date: "2001", price: "120"},
      {date: "2002", price: "33"},
      {date: "2003", price: "21"},
      {date: "2004", price: "51"},
      {date: "2005", price: "190"},
      {date: "2006", price: "120"},
      {date: "2007", price: "85"},
      {date: "2008", price: "221"},
      {date: "2009", price: "101"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Maxico",
    values: [
      {date: "2000", price: "50"},
      {date: "2001", price: "10"},
      {date: "2002", price: "5"},
      {date: "2003", price: "71"},
      {date: "2004", price: "20"},
      {date: "2005", price: "9"},
      {date: "2006", price: "220"},
      {date: "2007", price: "235"},
      {date: "2008", price: "61"},
      {date: "2009", price: "10"}
    ]
  }
];

var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var margin = 50;
var duration = 250;

var lineOpacity = "0.25";
var lineOpacityHover = "0.85";
var otherLinesOpacityHover = "0.1";
var lineStroke = "1.5px";
var lineStrokeHover = "2.5px";

var circleOpacity = '0.85';
var circleOpacityOnLineHover = "0.25"
var circleRadius = 3;
var circleRadiusHover = 6;


/* Format Data */
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");
data.forEach(function(d) { 
  d.values.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.price = +d.price;    
  });
});


/* Scale */
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date))
  .range([0, width-margin]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].values, d => d.price)])
  .range([height-margin, 0]);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

/* Add SVG */
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", (width+margin)+"px")
  .attr("height", (height+margin)+"px")
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


/* Add line into SVG */
var line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.date))
  .y(d => yScale(d.price));

let lines = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'lines');

lines.selectAll('.line-group')
  .data(data).enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'line-group')  
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title-text")
        .style("fill", color(i))        
        .text(d.name)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", (width-margin)/2)
        .attr("y", 5);
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      svg.select(".title-text").remove();
    })
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'line')  
  .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
  .style('stroke', (d, i) => color(i))
  .style('opacity', lineOpacity)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll('.line')
     .style('opacity', otherLinesOpacityHover);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
     .style('opacity', circleOpacityOnLineHover);
      d3.select(this)
        .style('opacity', lineOpacityHover)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStrokeHover)
        .style("cursor", "pointer");
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll(".line")
     .style('opacity', lineOpacity);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
     .style('opacity', circleOpacity);
      d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStroke)
        .style("cursor", "none");
    });


/* Add circles in the line */
lines.selectAll("circle-group")
  .data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
  .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(d => d.values).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "circle")  
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)     
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .text(`${d.price}`)
        .attr("x", d => xScale(d.date) + 5)
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.price) - 10);
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .selectAll(".text").remove();
    })
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
  .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.price))
  .attr("r", circleRadius)
  .style('opacity', circleOpacity)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("r", circleRadiusHover);
      })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.select(this) 
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("r", circleRadius);  
      });


/* Add Axis into SVG */
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append('text')
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .text("Total values");
```

```css
svg {
    font-family: Sans-Serif, Arial;
}
.line {
  stroke-width: 5;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path {
  stroke: black;
}

.text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.title-text {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My intention is to build a chart where the overlapping lines are colored based on the entry with the greater value in all portions of overlapping sections of the two lines.

If the blue line exceeds the yellow line at for any portion, that portion of should be coloured blue.

Similarly, if the yellow line exceeds the blue line at for any portion, that portion of should be coloured yellow.

For the above example, the following image is my intended output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to remodel your data such that you will have an array that will contain objects of type: {name, price1, price2}

```
const areaData = [];
data[0].values.forEach((value, index) => {
  areaData.push({date: value.date, price1: value.price, price2: data[1].values[index].price})
})
```

After that you will have to define 2 areas: one for the inner space between points (all area) and one that will fill only when line 2 points are above line 1

```
var innerArea = d3.area()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y0(d => yScale(d.price2))
    .y1(d => yScale(d.price1));

var line2PositiveArea = d3.area()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y0(d => yScale(Math.min(d.price1, d.price2)))
    .y1(d => yScale(d.price2));
```

having this you can define a clipping mask on your svg that will use to clip the positive filled area with inner area surface definition:

```
svg
  .append('defs')
  .append('mask')
  .attr('id', 'hole')
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', d => innerArea(areaData))
  .attr('fill', '#fff')
```

Then you can add your areas to the representation just above the line:

```
svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', d => innerArea(areaData))
  .attr('fill', (d, i) => color(i))

svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', d => line2PositiveArea(areaData))
  .attr('fill', (d, i) => color())
  .attr('mask', 'url(#hole)');
```

Here is the full working js code

```
var data = [

  {
    name: "Canada",
    values: [
      {date: "2000", price: "200"},
      {date: "2001", price: "120"},
      {date: "2002", price: "33"},
      {date: "2003", price: "21"},
      {date: "2004", price: "51"},
      {date: "2005", price: "190"},
      {date: "2006", price: "120"},
      {date: "2007", price: "85"},
      {date: "2008", price: "221"},
      {date: "2009", price: "101"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Maxico",
    values: [
      {date: "2000", price: "50"},
      {date: "2001", price: "10"},
      {date: "2002", price: "5"},
      {date: "2003", price: "71"},
      {date: "2004", price: "20"},
      {date: "2005", price: "9"},
      {date: "2006", price: "220"},
      {date: "2007", price: "235"},
      {date: "2008", price: "61"},
      {date: "2009", price: "10"}
    ]
  }
];

var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var margin = 50;
var duration = 250;

var lineOpacity = "0.25";
var lineOpacityHover = "0.85";
var otherLinesOpacityHover = "0.1";
var lineStroke = "1.5px";
var lineStrokeHover = "2.5px";

var circleOpacity = '0.85';
var circleOpacityOnLineHover = "0.25"
var circleRadius = 3;
var circleRadiusHover = 6;


/* Format Data */
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");
data.forEach(function(d) { 
  d.values.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.price = +d.price;    
  });
});


/* Scale */
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date))
  .range([0, width-margin]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data[0].values, d => d.price)])
  .range([height-margin, 0]);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

/* Add SVG */
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", (width+margin)+"px")
  .attr("height", (height+margin)+"px")

var innerArea = d3.area()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y0(d => yScale(d.price2))
    .y1(d => yScale(d.price1));

var line2PositiveArea = d3.area()
    .x(d => xScale(d.date))
    .y0(d => yScale(Math.min(d.price1, d.price2)))
    .y1(d => yScale(d.price2));


const areaData = [];
data[0].values.forEach((value, index) => {
  areaData.push({date: value.date, price1: value.price, price2: data[1].values[index].price})
})
svg.append('defs').append('mask').attr('id', 'hole').append('path').attr('d', d => innerArea(areaData)).attr('fill', '#fff')


svg = svg.append('g')
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


/* Add line into SVG */
var line = d3.line()
  .x(d => xScale(d.date))
  .y(d => yScale(d.price));

let lines = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'lines');


const linesGroup = lines.selectAll('.line-group')
  .data(data).enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'line-group')  
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "title-text")
        .style("fill", color(i))        
        .text(d.name)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", (width-margin)/2)
        .attr("y", 5);
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      svg.select(".title-text").remove();
    })


svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', d => innerArea(areaData))
  .attr('fill', (d, i) => color(i))


svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', d => line2PositiveArea(areaData))
  .attr('fill', (d, i) => color())
  .attr('mask', 'url(#hole)'); 


linesGroup.append('path')
  .attr('class', 'line')  
  .attr('d', d => line(d.values))
  .style('stroke', (d, i) => color(i))
  .style('opacity', lineOpacity)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll('.line')
                    .style('opacity', otherLinesOpacityHover);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
                    .style('opacity', circleOpacityOnLineHover);
      d3.select(this)
        .style('opacity', lineOpacityHover)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStrokeHover)
        .style("cursor", "pointer");
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.selectAll(".line")
                    .style('opacity', lineOpacity);
      d3.selectAll('.circle')
                    .style('opacity', circleOpacity);
      d3.select(this)
        .style("stroke-width", lineStroke)
        .style("cursor", "none");
    });


/* Add circles in the line */
lines.selectAll("circle-group")
  .data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
  .style("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(d => d.values).enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "circle")  
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)     
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "text")
        .text(`${d.price}`)
        .attr("x", d => xScale(d.date) + 5)
        .attr("y", d => yScale(d.price) - 10);
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .selectAll(".text").remove();
    })
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.date))
  .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.price))
  .attr("r", circleRadius)
  .style('opacity', circleOpacity)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("r", circleRadiusHover);
      })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.select(this) 
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("r", circleRadius);  
      });


/* Add Axis into SVG */
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height-margin})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append('text')
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .text("Total values");
```